# Access props.children in Typescript/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an JSX Element which I assign as to a variable:

```
const test = <prettyDate value={new Date()} />
```

When I `console.log(prettyDate(test.props))` I get the following:

[image]

So, logically I thought I can do this `console.log(prettyDate(test.props.children))` and get this `2022/09/16 12:51` but instead I get an error. `Cannot destructure property 'value' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.`

How can I get this date out of there?

Comment: well i would expect more that you will try test.props.props.children

Comment: Nope, this throws an error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did it:

```
const myDate = prettyDate({ value: new Date().toString() });
console.log(myDate?.props.children)
```

> 09/20/2022 11:10 am

Feel free to comment why, I am a beginner. I think it's about how I pass props and looks like I pass an object, that is why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access props with prop name like console.log(test.props.value)

Comment: Unfortunately this gives an object back

Answer (score -1):

The type of introspection you're describing is not idiomatic React. If you need some data in a parent component and also in some descendant component, that data should be passed as props (or held in some state accessible by both components).

If you simply want to get a date string in the format depicted in your screenshot (`2022/09/16 12:51`), then you can create a function to do that and then use it in your component with a date instance:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwIYBMByiAUYBciYIAtgEYCmATgDSImoAeAMhWAOZQAWiAvIgCY6wGABtRAZShUYHPogDkABgUBKQgGdps9ogDeAKESIqFKCCpIpMjnlUA6NOimoqUHAxZtOXYWMnaHKoA3AYAvgYGoJCwCIjAcFQMUAAiqFAUuOjpFIRpGeqIWja6hsYQCFqIAJ7y2Rn27GYAYiDiAJoUrjghRogVYFUkcHU5jWYAsgjcPYgA1IgAjKHllVCI6HAkow1NqTk9K-1riDz89RTjUAAScBYah30DQzuXexOyIBkPvcam5pZEAADAAkemqYQA9GCnJgPHBVFCYRg4ZsSIjEMisDguIj8Fi4eiwkDQhEDM91hdrPIEkl0vkKHgKAB3RAMnq9Z5wUSXURwdg4KnSXpAA)

```ts
function padN (n: number, maxLength = 2, fillString = '0'): string {
  return String(n).padStart(maxLength, fillString);
}

function formatDate (date: Date): string {
  const y = date.getFullYear();
  const mo = date.getMonth() + 1;
  const dom = date.getDate();
  const h = date.getHours();
  const m = date.getMinutes();
  return `${y}/${padN(mo)}/${padN(dom)} ${padN(h)}:${padN(m)}`;
}

const dateStr = formatDate(new Date());
console.log(dateStr);
```

Compiled JS from the TS Playground link:

```js
"use strict";
function padN(n, maxLength = 2, fillString = '0') {
    return String(n).padStart(maxLength, fillString);
}
function formatDate(date) {
    const y = date.getFullYear();
    const mo = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const dom = date.getDate();
    const h = date.getHours();
    const m = date.getMinutes();
    return `${y}/${padN(mo)}/${padN(dom)} ${padN(h)}:${padN(m)}`;
}
const dateStr = formatDate(new Date());
console.log(dateStr);
```

Comment: Property 'value' is missing in type 'Date' but required in type '{ value: string | Date |  | null; }'

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73743843/access-props-children-in-typescript-react/73745375?noredirect=1#comment130221389_73745375) @KatharinaSchreiber Why did you copy and paste an error message as a comment and to what does it relate? It doesn't relate to the code in this answer.

Comment: I do have date passed as props, but i am still not able to access it.The error message above.